# imageView is null in recyclerview viewholder

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, nullpointerexception

I want to set an onClick Listener to the imageView present in the recycler view. But whenever I pass the imageview from onViewCreated() method from the fragment, it is still null and throws a NullPointerException when I invoke setOnClickListener.

These are kotlin classes.

```
class ShowDuesFragment : Fragment() {
    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? =
        inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_show, container, false)

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        val adapter = Adapter(mutableListOf(..), fragmentmanager!!, imageView)
        recycler_view.apply {
            layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity!!.applicationContext)
            setHasFixedSize(true)
            this.adapter = adapter
        }
    }
}

class Adapter(private val list: List<Due>, private val manager: FragmentManager, private val imageView: ImageView?) : RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewHolder> {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder =
        ViewHolder(
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(
                R.layout.card_view,
                parent,
                false
            ),
            parent.context,
            manager,
            imageView
        )

    override fun getItemCount() = list.size

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) = holder.putData(list[position])
}

class ViewHolder(itemView: View, context: Context, manager: FragmentManager, imageView: ImageView? = null) :
RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView), DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {
    lateinit var item: Due

    init {
        Log.i("ViewHolder", (imageView == null).toString()) //log prints 'true'
        imageView?.setOnClickListener {
            val popup = PopupMenu(context, it)
            popup.menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_popup, popup.menu)
            popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener { menuItem ->
                when (menuItem.itemId) {
                    R.id.notify -> {
                        val datePicker = DatePickerFragment()
                        datePicker.show(manager, "DatePickerFragment")
                    }
                }
                context.toast((item as Due).name)
                true
            }
            popup.show()
        }
    }

    fun putData(due: Due) {
        …
        item = due
    }
    …
}
```

The log message I get is true and when I click on the imageView, it does not respond to my clicks. How do I successfully implement an onClickListener to my imageView?

Comment: is your ```imageView``` in the ```R.layout.card_view``` layout ?

Comment: yes, my imageView is there in R.layout.card_view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ViewHolder class should be inside the Adapter as an inner class. By doing so, imageView is not null.
Something like this:-

```
class Adapter (
    private val list: List<Due>,
    private val manager: FragmentManager
    ) : RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapter.ViewHolder>() {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder =
        ViewHolder(
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(
            R.layout.card_view,
            parent,
            false
        ),
        parent.context
    )

    override fun getItemCount() = list.size

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) = holder.putData(list[position])

    inner class ViewHolder(itemView: View, context: Context) :
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        private lateinit var item: Due

        init {
            Log.i("ViewHolder", (imageView == null).toString()) //log prints 'false'
            itemView.dropdown_menu.setOnClickListener {
                val popup = PopupMenu(context, it)
                popup.menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_popup, popup.menu)
                popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener { menuItem ->
                    when (menuItem.itemId) {
                        R.id.notify -> {
                            val datePickerFragment = DatePickerFragment()
                            datePickerFragment.show(manager, "date picker")
                        }
                    }
                    true
                }
                popup.show()
            }
        }

        fun putData(due: Due) {
            …
        }
    }
}
```

And we instantiate the Adapter like:-

```
val adapter = Adapter(mutableListOf(…), fragmentmanager!!)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are never initializing the imageView. As you are using ( ?.) while setting onClickListner to ImageView, you are not getting any crash due to safe call. One better way to do this is:

class ShowDuesFragment : Fragment() {
    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? =
        inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_show, container, false)

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    val adapter = Adapter(mutableListOf(..), fragmentmanager!!)
    recycler_view.apply {
        layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity!!.applicationContext)
        setHasFixedSize(true)
        this.adapter = adapter
    }
}
```

}

class Adapter(private val list: List, private val manager: FragmentManager, private val imageView: ImageView?) : RecyclerView.Adapter {

```
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder =
    ViewHolder(
        LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(
            R.layout.card_view,
            parent,
            false
        ),
        parent.context,
        manager
    )

override fun getItemCount() = list.size

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) = holder.putData(list[position])
```

}

class ViewHolder(itemView: View, context: Context, manager: FragmentManager) :
RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView), DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {
    lateinit var item: Due

```
init {
    val imageView = itemView //Cast this to image view if required you can use itemView.findViewById for other //views. 
    Log.i("ViewHolder", (imageView == null).toString()) //log prints 'true'
    imageView?.setOnClickListener {
        val popup = PopupMenu(context, it)
        popup.menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_popup, popup.menu)
        popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener { menuItem ->
            when (menuItem.itemId) {
                R.id.notify -> {
                    val datePicker = DatePickerFragment()
                    datePicker.show(manager, "DatePickerFragment")
                }
            }
            context.toast((item as Due).name)
            true
        }
        popup.show()
    }
}

fun putData(due: Due) {
    …
    item = due
}
…
```

}

Answer (score 0):

should work if you change onViewCreated to:

```
   override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        val adapter = Adapter(mutableListOf(..), fragmentmanager!!, view.imageView) // Specify which imageView you mean, as there might be a bunch of these fragments or none, system doesn't know.
```

or, do the whole view.findViewById() thingy if you're not using the kotlinx thingies